Correct Method to Place Multiple Arrays in a Custom Flash Section in C using GCC
I need to store a constant array in flash memory at a specific location using GCC in my embedded C project. For a uint32_t value, I managed to do it like this, and it works:
const uint32_t __attribute__((section(".metadata.SW_VERSION_VALUE"))) SW_VERSION_VALUE = 11;
Now, I want to allocate space for two arrays in the same metadata section, one after the other, but I'm not sure how to do it correctly. Here is my current linker script snippet:
.metadata :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.metadata.METADATA_START_ADDR))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    FW_SIGNATURE_START = .;
    . += 256;
    KEEP(*(.metadata.FW_SIGNATURE))

    KEEP(*(.metadata.FW_PUBLIC_KEY_SIZE))
    . = ALIGN(4);
    FW_PUBLIC_KEY_START = .;
    . += 128;
    KEEP(*(.metadata.FW_PUBLIC_KEY))
    . = ALIGN(4);
} >FLASH_METADATA_APP1

And here is my attempt to define arrays in the metadata section:
const uint8_t __attribute__((section(".metadata.FW_SIGNATURE"))) FW_SIGNATURE[256] = { /* values */ };
const uint8_t __attribute__((section(".metadata.FW_PUBLIC_KEY"))) FW_PUBLIC_KEY[128] = { /* values */ };

Is this the correct approach to place these arrays in flash memory one after the other within the specified metadata section?

Did you try it?

FWIW, I would do the . += 128; parts since the memory will be "automatically" allocated by placing the arrays there. What I would do is something like ASSERT(SIZEOF(.metadata) == 256 + 128) or similar to make sure the metadata has the expected size. This will cross-validate your C code vs the linker script

The problem is that it does not work, I cannot see the values of my array in memory, I can see the other uint32_t values, but not the array.

So, I found out that in the linker script, it is not necessary to define the size of the allocated memory at all. The important thing is to specify the size in the C file – at least it seems to be working for me: const uint8_t __attribute__((section(".metadata.FW_SIGNATURE"))) FW_SIGNATURE[256];
